# How can I polyfill Promise with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I'm using webpack to bundle up my JavaScript. I'm depending on modules like [popsicle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popsicle) which use [any-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-promise).

Here's my code:

```
var popsicle = require('popsicle');
popsicle.get('/').then(function() {
  console.log('loaded URL');
});
```

This works fine in browsers where `Promise` is available, but [IE 11 does not provide Promise](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises). So I want to use [es6-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise) as a polyfill.

I tried adding an explicit `ProvidePlugin` to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'Promise': 'exports?global.Promise!es6-promise'
  })
]
```

But I still get the error in IE 11: `any-promise browser requires a polyfill or explicit registration e.g: require('any-promise/register/bluebird')`.

I tried explicitly attaching a global:

```
global.Promise = global.Promise || require('es6-promise');
```

But IE 11 gives a different error: `Object doesn't support this action`.

I also tried explicitly registering es6-promise:

```
require('any-promise/register/es6-promise');
var popsicle = require('popsicle');
```

This works, but I have to do it in every single file that loads `popsicle`. I want to just attach `Promise` to `window`.

**How can I ensure `window.Promise` is always defined, using webpack?**

[Full repo demo here](https://github.com/Wilfred/webpack_promise_demo).

Answer (score 69):

For people using babel in combination with webpack: you can use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

Just do `npm install --save "babel-polyfill"` and then add it as an entry point in your webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/js']
};
```

Or, instead of using the entire babel-polyfill you can install `core-js` and reference only the module you need.

```
module.exports = {
   entry: ['core-js/stable/promise', './app/js']
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This should be accepted answer. Although, my output JS file is now 150 kB (before ~50 kB).

Comment: @Bald Have you tried webpack 2? 
I haven't tried it myself but it should now support tree shaking. 
This will remove code that is imported but unused in the bundle that is output. So if you use the single import from core-js it might reduce the size.

Comment: No, I haven't, but I will :) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Webpack v3.11, TS v2.7.x and node > v9, supports dynamic module imports, the problem is that you cannot import the Promise polyfill, because the dynamic import depends also on Promises. Therefor I do it manually:

`if (!("Promise" in window)) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://../YourPromisePolyfill.js";
    head.appendChild(script as HTMLScriptElement);
}`

You can of course use require/import to load the package, but then it gets bundeled and will be downloaded, even when not needed

Comment: In core-js v3 it's `'core-js/stable/promise'`.

Comment: Babel-polyfill is deprecated in favour of core-js

Answer (score 20):

Option that worked for me. [es6-promise-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-promise) is designed to be included directly to the webpack builds. So:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'es6-promise-promise'
  })
]
```

Comment: still getting a `ReferenceError` in IE 11 when using the `ProvidePlugin` and then trying to do some `require.ensure`

Answer (score 10):

An updated and concise version of @asiniy's answer using the recently added `property` feature of [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), without the need to reference `es6-promise-promise`:

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ['es6-promise', 'Promise']
    })
```

For this to work don't forget to add `es6-promise` as a dependency of the project you want to polyfill `Promise` in.

Answer (score 6):

babel polyfill usually works, but this time for a vuejs(webpack1) project, somehow not working.

Fortunately, core-js works as a charm.

```
npm install core-js --save

module.exports = {
   entry: ['core-js/fn/promise', './app/js']
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Better use Bluebird

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'bluebird'
  }),

  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/es6-promise$/, 'bluebird'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it - try this in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.Promise!es6-promise'
  })
]
```

Note that you will need to install `imports-loader` and `exports-loader`:

`npm install --save imports-loader exports-loader`

Comment: That doesn't work in IE 11, same error: `any-promise browser requires a polyfill or explicit registration e.g: require('any-promise/register/bluebird')`

Comment: Hmm, worked for me in IE11, Win 8.1. Will try with your repo demo in a bit.

Comment: @faceyspacey.com yes, but I recently switched to polyfilling manually instead of via webpack - it's too much magic. See https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise#auto-polyfill.

Comment: @GabrielFlorit me too. that's exactly what i did with the promise package at the top of google lol

Comment: @GabrielFlorit How did you that?

Answer (score 1):

With Webpack 2 this is how I got it working.

First install with `npm install babel-polyfill`. Starting with NPM 5 `--save` can be omitted.

Then modify the webpack configuration with:

```
entry: {
  app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js']
}
```

Of course `./src/main.js` is different for every app.

Answer (score 0):

For those using CRA (create-react-app) you could use the polyfill they provide:

[react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill)

- `npm install react-app-polyfill` or `yarn add react-app-polyfill`
- In your `index.js` file: `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';`

Comment: @Man you could open a new question and give more details there

Answer (score 0):

In webpack after optimization from babel-polyfill to core-js's promise the code:

```
import 'core-js/library/es6/promise';
```

does not works.

But after changing code to:

```
import 'core-js/features/promise';
```

it works.