# Solve web-dev-server pixi.js "import does not provide an export named 'default'" conflict

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-development-server, pixi.js, lit

I'm trying to update an old site of mine that was using lit-element, pixi.js, and webpack to serve in dev and build.
The new version of lit-element is lit and they recommend to use web-dev-server as mean to serve the code locally but when i'm trying to do so I get an error from pixi.js

https://lit.dev/docs/tools/development/ (for reference)

> The requested module './../../../es6-promise-polyfill/promise.js' does
> not provide an export named 'Polyfill'

from what I found effectively the fill just provide an Immediately Invoked Function Expression while pixi.js is trying to do a module import

```
/*!
* @pixi/polyfill - v5.3.10
* Compiled Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:37:25 UTC
*
* @pixi/polyfill is licensed under the MIT License.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license
*/
import { Polyfill } from 'es6-promise-polyfill';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';

// Support for IE 9 - 11 which does not include Promises
if (!window.Promise) {
  window.Promise = Polyfill;
}
```

I didn't have this issue with lit-element and webpack and I'm not sure on how to solve this properly. I guess it's a bundling issue but this is really not my strength here.
Switching back to webpack seems to bring a whole lot other issues. (seems to be linked to this issue [Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507441/relative-references-must-start-with-either-or) but since the solution in it is to use web-dev-server instead of webpack, I'm running in circle)

Any advice on this issue would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: Please share your webpack config. Do you use Babel? If yes, please share your Babel config as well\,

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following, it should work. If it was previously exported as `default`, so it may not be finding it. To further understand see [SO here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38729616/6085193)

```
import { Polyfill } from 'es6-promise-polyfill';
// should be changed to below code
import Polyfill  from 'es6-promise-polyfill';
```

---

Bonus:

If you want to do it with web pack look [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41062991/6085193) use `babel-polyfill`

1. Add via `npm install --save "babel-polyfill"`
2. then add it as an entry point in your webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/js']
};
```